# Array of objects for loop change value versus array reconstruction

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have an array of objects

```
x = [{id:null},{id:null},{id:null},{id:null}];
```

Lets say that the values for the array changed

```
x = [{id:1},{id:3},{id:8},{id:12}];
```

And i wanted to revert the values to all null,which method will be faster for performance

A) Reconstructing the array again

```
 x=[];
 for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.id = null;
    x.push(obj);
 }
```

B) Resetting the values

```
for (var i in x) {
    x.id = null;
}
```

Comment: or if there would be another way to approach this please tell me

Comment: You have the code - why not test it Yourself?

Comment: You can test this yourself here: https://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have thousands of elements, you will never notice a difference in performances.

However the second solution is more clear than the first one.

Alternatively, to make it clear x is an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
  x[i].id = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your B will just add property `id` to your array and set it's value to 'null'. On top of that, you [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) use `for in` on arrays.

Fastest way would probably be:

```
var i = x.length;
while(i--){
    x[i].id = null;
}
```

But you wouldn't see the difference unless your array has thousands of elements, and probably [shouldn't even try to optimize](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) it for the performance, before you're sure that you need to. In most use cases readability of the code will be much more important than a few fragments of a second that you could gain.